# Yii2 get correct client IP

Tags: yii2, ip-address

I use this function for get client ip:

```
 $client  = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
```

You can see it here.
http://city.ru.xsph.ru/web/

But this address does not match the IP that use other hosts (the correct IP). For example:
https://hidemyna.me/en/ip/

Comment: do mark the correct answer that worked for you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Yii2 default method available in `YI2`

```
Yii::$app->getRequest()->getUserIP()
```

or if you are looking to save the current user ip into the database table i would recommend you to use the [`IPbehavior`](https://github.com/ruskid/yii2-ip-behavior) within the model like

```
public function behaviors() {
        return [
            ...
            'ip' => [
                'class' => IpBehavior::className(),
                'attributes' => [
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => ['created_ip', 'updated_ip'],
                    ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'updated_ip',
                ],
            ]
            ...
        ];
    }
```

Or like this. where value can be a string or an anonymous function that will return a string.

```
public function behaviors() {
    return [
        ...
        'ip' => [
            'class' => IpBehavior::className(),
            'createdIpAttribute' => 'created_ip',
            'updatedIpAttribute' => 'updated_ip',
            'value' => '127.0.0.1',
        ]
        ...
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to get client IP address you have to use this code:

```
 Yii::$app->request->userIP
```

Answer (score 0):

The prefered way of getting client ip is with `Yii::$app->request-remoteIp`
This method uses either `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` or ip headers (like *X-Forwarded-For*) that can be added by load balencers or proxy services.

there are however still situations where your public ip (https://hidemyna.me/en/ip/) and the ip that your appication is showing (http://city.ru.xsph.ru/web/) will be different - if you're on the same network as your app for example

Comment: But this IP not correct ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']). How to get the same ip that show online resources?